# How can i properly read my csv data?

Tags: python, csv

My data was like this :

```
{'yMax': u'156', 'xMax': u'4802', 'xMin': u'4770','yMin': u'141', 'id': '1', 'name': ''}
{'yMax': u'157', 'xMax': u'4895', 'xMin': u'4810','yMin': u'141', 'id': '2', 'name': ''}
```

in a `.txt` file, i had to change it per the requirement to a `.csv` file it now looks like this:

```
image     id    name    xMin    xMax    yMin    yMax
1-0.png   1             4770    4802    141     156
1-0.png   2             4810    4895    141     157
```

i used to read my `.txt` file using :

```
import ast
file = open("1-0.txt", 'r')
    labels1 = []
    for line in file.readlines():
        dicObj = ast.literal_eval(line.strip('\n'))
        labels1.append(dicObj)
```

basically as a list of dictionaries after transforming the string shaped `{}` in my txt file to dics. How can i now read the data from my new csv file that i described its shape above ?

Comment: use pandas it would be fairly easy in pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `csv.DictReader`

**Ex:**

```
import csv
labels1 = []
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for line in reader:
        labels1.append(line)
```

**[MoreInfo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)**

Comment: I want my final data to be in similar format to the code i shared on how i read the .txt, list of dictionaries, kindly refer to `label1` in my question which is a list of dictionaries(json).

Comment: It should be in the same pattern as the you mentioned. it should print each dict.

Comment: That's not how my snippet looks like. I dnt use ast module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to load your .csv as a DataFrame. This is a highly recommended datastructure due to its versatility.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Comment: The OP's file doesn't seem to be comma-separated.

Comment: @AshishAcharya pandas can figure out delimiter by itself.

Comment: You can use other delimeters when using this function as described in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html.

Comment: I want my final data to be in similar format to the code i shared on how i read the `.txt`, list of dictionaries.

Comment: I think you still need to do it like this: df = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True)

Comment: So that we can better understand what you are attempting to achieve. You are going from a ,txt file with the correct structure, to a .csv, then you want to load the .csv with the same structure as the one in the .txt file? Why? Why not read it directly from the .txt file? Let us know what data structure you have access to (the files) and what data structure you need in your code. You shouldn't need intermediate steps like making a .csv file to access a data structure that you already have access to.

Comment: It's weird i know had it all working then some tweaks and requirement changes all of a sudden and i'm new to python so no prior experience with pandas but it's definitely something i'll be checking very very soon, thanks for the time you've taken to answer and comment.

Comment: @user9686018, no worries, just let us know more details about what you are trying to achieve and we can give you some pointers towards tools which may make your life much easier.